# Frequency-wavenumber domain and fft2 command in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, frequency

I'd like to use numpy to preform a double frequency transform. I have some data that is in the space-time domain and I would like to look at it in the frequency-wavenumber domain. I think numpy's ft2 command can do this for me but I am a bit unsure how to implement it. My data is in a 2d array with shape `(864000, 2)` the first column is the spatial data and the second time. I tried the following,

```
ft2 = fft2(data)
plot(abs(ft2))
```

I get something that looks flat in the centre and blows up at the corners, which I dont think is right. Anyone know how to do this correctly???

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 1D sample in which case you want `numpy.fft.fft`. You should apply it to the spatial data. But note that, regular FFT/DFT assumes your samples are taken from uniform time intervals.

Comment: Is the 864000-length dimension a "flattened" grid of some sort? `fft2` expects things to be a 2d grid (e.g. 100x100) instead of a 1D flattened version of the same thing (e.g. a 10000-length vector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I had misunderstood the usage, for fft2 the data needs to be an n by m matrix with each  row should representing a different time increment, and each column should representing a different location.